# Why friend function is not able to access private members of the class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

While executing this program, i am getting following compilation error:

```
template.cpp: In function ‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, currency&)’:
template.cpp:8: error: ‘int currency::doller’ is private
template.cpp:25: error: within this context
template.cpp:9: error: ‘int currency::cents’ is private
template.cpp:25: error: within this context
```

This is the c++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class currency
{
    private: 
        int doller;
        int cents;

    public:
        currency():doller(0),cents(0) {}
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, const currency& c );
        friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, const currency& c);

        /*friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, const currency& c)
        {
            in >> c.doller >> c.cents;
            return in;
        } */
};

istream& operator>> (istream& in, currency& c)
{
    in >> c.doller >> c.cents;
    return in;
} 

ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, const currency& c )
{
    stream << "(" << c.doller << ", " << c.cents << ")";
    return stream;
}

template <class T>
void function(T data)
{
    cout << "i am in generalized template function: " << data << endl;
}

template<>
void function (int data)
{
    cout << "This is: specialized for int" << data << endl;
}

int main()
{
    currency c;
    cin >> c;
    function (c);
    function (3.14);
    function ('a');
    function (12);
    return 0;
}
```

at the same time std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const currency&) not giving any error. I want to understand is there anything wrong in the program??

Also, while i am giving the defition inside the class this is the error:

```
template.cpp: In function ‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const currency&)’:
template.cpp:18: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ in ‘in >> c->currency::doller’
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong signature in your `operator>>` definition, which means you are declaring and defining a different operator. You need to remove the `const` from the `friend istream& operator` declaration for it to be the definition of the `friend` operator:

```
friend
istream& operator>> (istream& in, currency& c)
//
```

The ambiguous overload is for the same reason. You have two functions that match. The fix suggested above would solve both problems.

Comment: according to the logic of it`s operator currency shouldn't be const, as he modifies it in this statement in >> c.doller >> c.cents; So it is better to change signature of friend (omit const)

Comment: Thanks for very quick response.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of the `operator>>` does not match the one declared as friend of the class:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, currency& c);        // outside class
istream& operator>> (istream& in, const currency& c);  // friend class
//                                ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, my signature didn't match too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the `const` signature in the method declaration:

```
friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, currency& c);
```

The function that you *define* doesn't have the `const` in it, so it's not the function that you declare as `friend` and hence cannot access the `private` members. Note that declaring the `currency` object `const` doesn't make sense either, since you change it using the instream operator.